# Select records from 2 weeks prior using timestamps in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I have records in a table that are stored using php's `strtotime` function. What I need and don't have any experience with is **querying the database for all records within 2 weeks**.

I'm sorry I have no code to show for as using timestamps is all so new to me.

Comment: You have numeric timestamps in the DB.  Do you know how to generate a timestamp for "2 weeks ago"?  If so, you're literally comparing integers in your query.

Comment: @Madbreaks I have no idea how to handle timestamps, so the answer is no i dont know how to do this

Comment: +1 for unexplained down-vote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your date is stored as a timestamp, it's easy enough to take two weeks off it:

```
select
    *
from
    yourTable
where
    dateField<=UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
    and dateField>=(SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP()- 60*60*24*14)
```

As these are all in seconds, just subtract 60 seconds x 60 minutes x 24 hours x 14 days and you have your required condition.

FYI: A timestamp is simply the number of seconds that have passed since the [unix epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) so addition or subtraction is really rather simple. You can also use PHP's [mktime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) to generate a timestamp if you want a particular date.

Comment: Calculating the seconds over and over again is something e.g. MySQL wouldn't optimize and it would have to calculate it each time you execute the query. bishop's answer is therefor much better because it can be easily optimized by the DBMS. This comment might not be true in the future or for any other DBMS!

Comment: @Fleshgrinder Yes, but explaining it in seconds (ie, what a timestamp is) is probably more beneficial in the long run than only teaching someone to use time compared to the mysql `now()` function - kinda hard to use that if you want to specify a particular two week gap :)

Comment: Absolutely right, but you could simply include `1209600` in your query, because your detailed and perfect explanation directly follows. Upvoted yours too. ;) Oh and `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is a magic constant and theoretically faster than `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`; but please note that I never made any benchmarks for it (a simple assumption from knowledge of many other programming stuff).

Comment: @Fleshgrinder Yeah, that's why I added the bit about PHP's mktime as well in the answer :) Thanks!

Comment: @Fleshgrinder: On performance, I'll add that NOW() is a [synonym](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html) for CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, as are a few other time functions. Interestingly, UNIX_TIMESTAMP isn't.  Who knew?  Thanks for up-vote.

Answer (score 5):

From memory:

```
SELECT * FROM Foo WHERE bar BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 2 WEEK) AND NOW()
```

Replace NOW() with anything that is timestamp related.  I am currently wrestling with my tablet so I can't check if this is exactly right.  Good luck.

Comment: You're forgetting the date_sub() function I think.